# jquery chosen multiple : how to keep menu open between selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen to give my `<select>` a proper look and a search input.

The problem is that with a `<select multiple>` when the user open the dropdown menu to choose the options he wants I want to keep the dropdown open between the clicks. It is really annoying to have the re-open the menu between each option selection.

I searched through the [Chosen documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and through the internet but I couldn't find to do it with Chosen.

Here is how I wrote my `<select>` and how applied Chosen to it (nothing special) :

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="foo" class="chosenSelect">
    <option value="NULL" disabled>Chose multiple somthing</option>';
    <option value="bar1">foobar1</option>';
    <option value="bar2">foobar2</option>';
    <option value="bar3">foobar3</option>';
</select>
```

and

```
$('.chosenSelect').chosen();
```

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `Chosen` library; so if there exists a better solution in the library itself, I'd defer to that solution.

However, if you do not find a better solution, and you still need the functionality, you can use this little *hack*.

```
$('.chosen-results').bind('click', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().siblings('.chosen-choices').click()
  });
});
```

I reiterate, this is a hack and you should only use this if you've found nothing else. I'll edit the answer if I find something better.

Comment: Thank you ! This hack seems to work perfectly. At least I can now spend time on something else knowing I have a back up plan if I don't discover a prettier solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works for keeping drop-down menu open, however, the search criteria don't get kept. If I have a super long dropdown list, the scroll bar will bounce to the top. Is there a way we can keep all previous search and also the position of the scroll bar?

Answer (score 5):

Set `hide_results_on_select` to `false`.

Comment: This option may be added later, however, this is the right way to do that as mentioned by @squgeim in his accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a click trigger to the change event

```
$("select").chosen().change(function() {
 $(".search-field").trigger("click")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution @squgeim posted.
However, after I selected something, the search criteria don't get kept. If I have a super long dropdown list, the scroll bar will bounce to the top.
In order to keep my previous search criteria, I made some update on @squgeim's answer:

```
//restore previous search value
var chosenSearchValue = "";
$(".chosen-container-multi .search-field input").keyup(function(){
    chosenSearchValue = $(this).val();
})

//make chosen multiple select dropdown menu stay open after click
$('.chosen-results').bind('click', function(e) {
    if (chosenSearchValue){
        $(this).parents(".chosen-container-multi").find(".search-field input").val(chosenSearchValue);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().siblings('.chosen-choices').click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use set `hide_results_on_select` to `false` if you want to keep showing the dropdown after chosing in option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).